# Dependencies using hardcoded paths to the host OS filesystem

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

How do I deal with dependencies in my snap that use hardcoded paths to the host OS filesystem? Can they be snapped at all?

For example, one of my dependencies tries to access the /lib/something directory on the host OS file system. Is there any way to map that to the snap directory, besides altering the source code?

Thanks

Comment: The snapcraft-preload part seems to have resolved some of my issues.

https://github.com/sergiusens/snapcraft-preload